# vb.net Formating a date as CCCC-MM-DD?

Tags: vb.net

How do I format a date to CCCC-MM-YY in vb.net ?

Comment: MM is 2 digit month & YY is 2 digit year, but what is CCCC?

Comment: @saunderl I think he means CCYY.

Comment: So, CCYY stands for Century-Year, right?  So why the second set of YY at the end. (When I first saw this post, I thought I saw YYYY-MM-DD and was going to answer that format question - now I am curious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) is a list of all of the supported date format flags for .NET.

Additionally, John Sheehan has put together some useful cheat sheets for string formatting - and other useful information.  You can find those [here](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets/).